# Why did I receive duplicate newsletters?

Tags: bug, status-completed, newsletter

I subscribed for some newsletters yesterday. I got some of them today, 2 of which arrived twice:

- IT Security Weekly Newsletter - Tuesday, August 2, 2011
- Personal Productivity Weekly Newsletter - Tuesday, August 2, 2011

That's it. I hope this isn't a duplicate bug. :P

Comment: This bug seems to have affected a few other people too, one of whom is in the office. We're investigating what went wrong -- sorry about the dupe emails :(

Comment: Does your account have multiple registered OpenIDs?

Comment: @M. Tibbits could be, i'm not really sure. Do you know a way to check that information?

Comment: Nope.  Sorry.  I'm not an all powerful mod.  You might send an email to team (at) stackoverflow.com and ask if they've got more than one OpenID registered to your account.

Answer (score 5):

A small subset of newsletters were sent twice, but sadly, after investigating, we're still unclear on *why*.

We've added a last-second dupe-thwarting check, as well as more extensive logging around our newsletter-sending code. So, hopefully, this bug won't re-surface, but if it does, we'll have more tools at our disposal while debugging.

Sorry again about the extra emails.

Comment: No worries, GMail is smart enough to stack them ;)