# Duplicate newsletters

Tags: bug, newsletter

For the past week or two I've been getting two copies of each of the newsletters I'm subscribed to, just seconds apart.

A few minutes ago I received two copies of the ServerFault newsletter. Here are the message IDs and last `Received` headers.

Copy 1:

```
Received: from MzU1Mzk4OA (stackoverflow.com [198.252.206.71])
    by ismtpd0022p1iad2.sendgrid.net (SG) with HTTP id FlHMILhNSdiIE3mZw32OVA
    Tue, 16 Oct 2018 18:19:13.155 +0000 (UTC)
Message-ID: <FlHMILhNSdiIE3mZw32OVA@ismtpd0022p1iad2.sendgrid.net>
```

Copy 2:

```
Received: from MzU1Mzk4OA (stackoverflow.com [198.252.206.71])
    by ismtpd0047p1mdw1.sendgrid.net (SG) with HTTP id U3oBrJ7PQTG42GxHf084_g
    Tue, 16 Oct 2018 18:19:35.493 +0000 (UTC)
Message-ID: <U3oBrJ7PQTG42GxHf084_g@ismtpd0047p1mdw1.sendgrid.net>
```

UPDATE:

This seems to be intermittent, as I didn't receive duplicates yesterday. Looking through my trash I see the following:

```
2018-10-17: 1 Unix & Linux
2018-10-16: 2 Server Fault
2018-10-15: 1 English Language & Usage
2018-10-12: 1 Super User
2018-10-09: 1 SF
2018-10-08: 2 ELU
2018-10-05: 1 SU
2018-10-02: 1 each SO and UL
2018-09-28: 2 SU
2018-09-26: 1 UL
2018-09-25: 1 SF
2018-09-24: 1 ELU
```

Comment: Reversion of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100641/21960) perhaps?